# Timed out Availability of block devices

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, raid, systemd, lvm

On a fresh **Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) Server** install, the `blk-availability.service` always killed by timeout at shutdown.

I think the dependency of this service is bad, but I don't know what would be the good shutdown order for this.

*An almost same config has been worked on **Xenial**...*

### The disk sub-system is

- NVMe SSD *(Samsung 970 EVO MZ-V7E250BW)*

  - **EFI** partition
  - **boot** partition
  - LVM phisical volume

    - **root** logical volume
    - **swap** logical volume
    - **data** logical volume
- 2 pcs. HDDs in RAID1 (*but the `md0` is not used yet*)

### Journal

```
systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
systemd[1]: Stopped Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
kernel: usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 2
systemd[1]: blk-availability.service: Stopping timed out. Terminating.
systemd[1]: blk-availability.service: Control process exited, code=killed status=15
blkdeactivate[2447]:   [MD]: deactivating raid1 device md0... resync action in progress...
systemd[1]: blk-availability.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
systemd[1]: Stopped Availability of block devices.
systemd[1]: Stopping iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)...
iscsid[951]: iscsid shutting down.
systemd[1]: Stopped iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
systemd[1]: Stopped target Network is Online.
systemd[1]: Stopped Wait for Network to be Configured.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Network.
systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot/efi...
systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/user/1000...
systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/8a3d99d0-683e-xxxx-xxxx-9765162cc070...
systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/AB9E-5A2C.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/xxx_server_ssd/swap.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/8a3d99d0-683e-xxxx-xxxx-9765162cc070.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-eatHKVdbDuw5L5RXXXXXXX2yJn7QosUWvV2IIApCOG73Bc2CbrUabBC6L3dh0N2D.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-xxx_server_ssd-swap.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-1.
systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/xxx_server_ssd-swap.
systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d7cc70cc-0f33-xxxx-xxxx-cc21d3ed1232.
systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
systemd[1]: Stopped target Network (Pre).
systemd[1]: Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
```

## systemctl cat blk-availability.service

```
# /lib/systemd/system/blk-availability.service
[Unit]
Description=Availability of block devices
After=lvm2-activation.service lvm2-lvmetad.service iscsi-shutdown.service iscsi.service iscsid.service fcoe.service
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/sbin/blkdeactivate -u -l wholevg -m disablequeueing -r wait
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

## Questions

Is this an Ubuntu bug? How can I solve it?

---

**Update:** I created a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1780196

**Update 2:** I found the commit where introduced this `blkdeactivate`: [lvm2 upstream: c698ee14bbb1310cf2383c8977d14a8e29139f8c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=commit;h=c698ee14bbb1310cf2383c8977d14a8e29139f8c)

> Traverses the tree of block devices and tries to deactivate them.
>   Currently, it supports device-mapper-based devices together with LVM.
>   See man/blkdeactivate.8 for more info.
>
> It is targeted for use during shutdown to properly deactivate the
>   whole block device stack - systemd and init scripts are provided as
>   well. However, it might be used directly on command line too.

In this case, this stuff runs too early, as I think.

**Update 3:** I think it can be fixed in 2 ways:

- `blkdeactivate` should handles properly the syncing software-raid arrays
- re-order this service, to be after the "standard" software-raid deinit

Comment: Not all NVMe's are created equal. It's best to include the make and model.

Comment: This *might* be helpful: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1299178

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I added the type of the NVMe and checked the mentioned bug, but as I see, this doesn't help me.

Comment: The 970 is brand new drive. In benchmark testing they used kernel version **4.17**: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=samsung-970-evo&num=4